# Why wont this event listener work for multiple keys when in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, keyboard

**First code**--> My first example does not work, and I am not sure why. I would say a condition, like `if(keys[38])` where 38 in the example would be the `event.keyCode`. If true, it should execute the if statement.

**second code**--> The second example only works when there is one key being pushed, and I am not sure why it does not work for multiple keys, either. For multiple keys I would say something like `if(keys[38] && keys[40])`, but that will not work, it should be noted, however, that it would work for just one key, like just `if(keys[38])`.

I know that there are other ways to get this to work, but my objective is to figure out why *these* code pieces do not work.

first code piece:

```
var keys = [];
  addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    keys[event.keyCode] = event.type == "keydown";
    event.preventDefault();
  });
  /*conditions*/
```

second code piece:

```
var keys = [];
  addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    keys[event.keyCode] = event.type == "keydown";
    event.preventDefault();
    /* conditions with multiple keys accessing by if(keys[38] && keys[40]*/
  });
```

thanks ahead of time :)

Comment: In "First code", it looks like the conditional is evaluated before any key press event is handled, therefore keys[x] will be `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press multiple keys, your addEventListener no longer listens to your first keypress. That's why your if statement is failing. You can test that out on the first example on http://api.jquery.com/event.which/ Try holding one key, then holding a second key, and then releasing the second key. You'll notice that the first key won't be logged anymore.

*edit: A way around that would be to implement it like this:

```
var keys = {};

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keys[e.which] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    delete keys[e.which];
});
```

The difference is that in this case, nothing is getting overwritten, where as in your example your first key press is getting overwritten (and no longer saved) by the second key press.

Comment: but, shouldn't the values still be held in the variable `keys`?